# EF: Attaching entity to context and assigning to new instance of same entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So I understand that in Entity Framework you can Attach an entity to the current context and it will begin with an EntityState of Unchanged. I also get that changing individual properties of that entity from that point on would cause Entity framework to only update those properties that were changed instead of every property. However, I was wondering what would happen if we attached an entity then immediately set it equal to a new instance of that entity type. Would EF mark that entire entity as dirty (EntityState.Modified) or would it still only update the changed properties?

Comment: Why don't you try it out?

Comment: I don't know how to check the Entity State while in the debugger as well. I can do with either.

Comment: Would I just set that entry equal to a variable and set a breakpoint on that?

Answer (score 0):

So in regards to my question, doing what I mentioned would changed the entry state to Detached which will not update on a save. If you want to modify an entity by setting it equal to another object then you must track the entity by using the .Entry method of your data context. The code will look something like this:

```
//We query local context first to see if it's there.
var attachedEntity = db.Carts.Local.Find(newCart.Id);

//We have it in the context, need to update.
if (attachedEntity != null) {
    var attachedEntry = _context.Entry(attachedEntity);
    attachedEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(newCart);
}
```

You can find the full example [here](http://blog.maskalik.com/entity-framework/2013/12/23/entity-framework-updating-database-from-detached-objects/). You can find it at the bottom of the page as the last code sample. The example is optimized to update only the properties that changed when it can.

There are a couple drawbacks to using this however. One being that as of now, Entity Framework does not support updating navigation properties (the relating entities) using .CurrentValues.SetValues(). This also only works when you are currently tracking the entity you want to update. So you might need to make another call to the database to do update it.